# Is there a benefit to using a filter function within an ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular

I found a few answers on here where people recommend using a line of code similar to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of filter(myArray)">
```

However, the `filter(myArray)` is run *constantly*.

I've found that keeping 2 arrays like below is much more efficient.

```
<div *ngFor="let x of filteredArray">
```

Code

```
let fullArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let filteredArray = []

onFilterEvent() {
    filteredArray = fullArray.filter(x => /* filtering logic */)
}
```

The downside here is that I'm constantly rewriting the contents of `filteredArray`. However, it's only run when the logic for filtering is needed to, instead of constantly.

Is there any reason to use the first method? It's still doing the same work, but it's doing it over and over.

Comment: `I found a few answers on here where people recommend` where did you find it?

Comment: These  two have nothing to do with each other, in your second example, who's calling the `onFilterEvent` ? in the first one, change detection will call `filter()`

Answer (score 2):

Angular recommends moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself for **performance** reasons. You should do the filtering inside the component instead of constantly running pipe or function:

> The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a benefit to using a filter function within an ngFor?

Not particularly for `*ngFor`, but actually yes. With `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` you can have two benefits by using this approach:

- much better performance than when filtering constantly
- less memory consumption as additional variable isn't needed

Consider this example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="refilter()">Refilter</button>
    <h3>Filtered array</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let i of filter(array)">{{i}}</div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App {
  array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

  constructor(protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  filter(array: Array) {
    console.log('array filtered!');
    return array.filter(i => i < 5);
  }

  refilter() {
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

PLNKR: https://plnkr.co/edit/qkkW9U7rDlI6eSYGEUrf?p=info

Otherwise to achieve the same goal you could use [impure pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#impure-pipes), what is strongly not recommended for sorting, filtering, ordering and similar demanding to CPU operations.